# Add Custom Type to Rails User Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to make a rails app that has two kinds of users (player and admin) but will only allow registration of players. I cannot get the registration to work and receive the error "Type can't be blank" when trying to insert into the database.

```
UsersController < ApplicationController 

def new
  @player = Player.new
  @player.type = 'Player'
end

def create
  @player = Player.new(params[:player])
  @player.type = 'Player'
  if @player.save
    redirect_to @player
  else
    render 'new'
end
```

My /signup lets the user submit e-mail and password. The SQL insertion works in the admin panel and looks like

```
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("type", "email", "city", "display_name", "tags", "game_id", "affiliation", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["type", "Player"], ["email", "d"], ["city", ""], ["display_name", "d"], ["tags", ""], ["game_id", 1], ["affiliation", ""], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$AfuUFDjJRnoAl2fL3MGfNO9AEve.YNGNSp2SUhpfOiV6KuXuve2qC"], ["created_at", "2015-12-21 02:04:33.485089"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-21 02:04:33.485089"]]
```

So I am trying to allow the insertion of just Player types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"Type can't be blank"
```

You are getting this error probably because you have a validation in your `Player` model that `type` can't be blank.

To solve the problem, either remove that validation if you are planning to set the type manually in your controller, or add a type field and submit the type along with the player object in the player form.

Comment: Great that worked! Is my syntax right for adding to the type field, though? My SQL is now


    SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "cccccc"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$49GeV1gRDExnrbpbG25CIOdgbHtMrrdtRYYzKRXtEW33y06VWftCa"], ["created_at", "2015-12-21 03:12:17.655950"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-21 03:12:17.655950"]]

Comment: Looks like you are not saving the `type` anymore. Can you show your model and controller's latest code?